# Capture date range of different dateYear , DateMonth columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that captures monthly data using a dateYear and dateMonth to record date. I;m having trouble capturing data between two different years.

For example : between dateYear 2015 and dateMonth 09 through dateMonth 02 and dateYear 2016

In english  , between September 2015 and Feb 2016

whats the best way to go about this.. Ive tried grouping through the where clause but the months overlap..

is there a date function or concatenation method i should use?>

```
SELECT 
   prodDays
   ,hours
FROM Table 
WHERE 1=1
   AND date_year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2016
```

Comment: What are the datatypes for `dateYear` and `dateMonth`

Comment: They are of datatype INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for this where clause:

```
where (date_year = 2015 and date_month >= 9) or (date_year = 2016 and date_month <= 2)
```

Comment: That works great in capturing both sets of dates. Is this the best practice or do you know of other methods?.. I was thinking of creating a YearMonth field to make it easier but that might be too many steps..

Comment: In general, it's better to have date field. having Year and Month, field is not recommend. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as answer. thanks